# Wild card search required instead of specific field name in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, kibana-4

I am working on elasticsearch 2.3.3. While querying the search, I am getting results only when field name is specified. ie

```
GET /mydocs/_search?q=file.content:cat
```

but I need to search without giving the field name. How is it possible?

Response from http://localhost:9200/mydocs

```
 {  
 "mydocs":{  
  "aliases":{  

  },
  "mappings":{  
     "indexdocument":{  
        "properties":{  
           "docLocation":{  
              "type":"string",
              "index":"not_analyzed",
              "store":true
           },
           "documentType":{  
              "type":"string",
              "store":true
           },
           "file":{  
              "type":"attachment",
              "fields":{  
                 "content":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"full"
                 },
                 "author":{  
                    "type":"string"
                 },
                 "title":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
                    "analyzer":"full"
                 },
                 "name":{  
                    "type":"string"
                 },
                 "date":{  
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                 },
                 "keywords":{  
                    "type":"string"
                 },
                 "content_type":{  
                    "type":"string"
                 },
                 "content_length":{  
                    "type":"integer"
                 },
                 "language":{  
                    "type":"string"
                 }
              }
           },
           "filePermissionInfo":{  
              "properties":{  
                 "accessControlType":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "store":true
                 },
                 "accountValue":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "store":true
                 },
                 "fileSystemRights":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "store":true
                 },
                 "isInherited":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "store":true
                 }
              }
           },
           "id":{  
              "type":"double",
              "store":true
           },
           "lastModifiedDate":{  
              "type":"date",
              "store":true,
              "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
           },
           "title":{  
              "type":"string",
              "store":true,
              "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "settings":{  
     "index":{  
        "creation_date":"1466482894271",
        "analysis":{  
           "filter":{  
              "snowball":{  
                 "type":"snowball",
                 "language":"English"
              }
           },
           "analyzer":{  
              "full":{  
                 "filter":[  
                    "lowercase",
                    "snowball"
                 ],
                 "type":"custom",
                 "tokenizer":"standard"
              }
           }
        },
        "number_of_shards":"5",
        "number_of_replicas":"1",
        "uuid":"PpxcRl29QTCPtFcsd3PHtw",
        "version":{  
           "created":"2030399"
        }
     }
  },
  "warmers":{  

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get from `GET /mydocs`?

Comment: Do you want to perform a `querystring` query across all string fields? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: @RussCam User is not aware of any field names,they will enter the text to search(I am using kibana). We internally need to check whether the given text is contained in the title or attached content. Is it possible using kibana?

Comment: You should be able to change `index.query.default_field` for the index to point to another field, and use `copy_to` to copy `title` and attached content to that field at index time.

Comment: @RussCam Thank you. It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per @RussCam's comment, setting index.query.default_field will help to make a default field search
To set this using Nest client, refer the below link
[Set index.query.default_field using NEST Client c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967551/set-index-query-default-field-using-nest-client-c-sharp)